# Bad operand types for binary operator '+' ERROR when adding indices of an arrayList

Tags: java

When trying to find the median of an arrayList, I get an error...

bad operand types for binary operator '+'

```
  public static void printMedian(int x[]){

ArrayList sortedList = new ArrayList();

    sortedList.add(1);
    sortedList.add(2);
    sortedList.add(3);
    sortedList.add(4);

}

double median = 0;
if (sortedList.size() % 2 == 0)

{
  int firstIndex = (sortedList.size() - 1) / 2;
  int secondIndex = sortedList.size() / 2;
  median = ((sortedList.get(firstIndex)) + (sortedList.get(secondIndex))) / 2;
}

else  
{
  int singleIndex = (sortedList.size() - 1) / 2;
  median = sortedList.get(singleIndex);
}
System.out.println("The median is " + median);
```

}

It appears I can't add the two indices of the list, which is odd since they are both integers.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Unless you use generics on your `ArrayList` they will be treated as Objects

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use generics on your ArrayList they will be treated as Objects

```
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList();

        sortedList.add(1);
        sortedList.add(2);
        sortedList.add(3);
        sortedList.add(4);

        int firstIndex = (sortedList.size() - 1) / 2;
        int secondIndex = sortedList.size() / 2;
        double median = ((sortedList.get(firstIndex)) + (sortedList.get(secondIndex))) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are both of type Object.  Simply casting to double should solve your issue.

```
median = (double) (sortedList.get(firstIndex)) + (double) (sortedList.get(secondIndex)) / 2;
```

Comment: Great! :) If this helped you can you please accept the answer by hitting the check mark  on the left?